# Joined Stack Overflow. Twice!

Tags: support, bug, developer-story

Browsing the site, I came across this Developer Story:

[image: Developer Story]

I'm not sure what to make out of those two join dates. The only explanation I have is, that this is what an account looks like, once it got merged into another account.

Is this correct? Are there any other reasons, why an account would show multiple join dates?

Or is this simply a bug?

Comment: Now you know: You are a split personality ;)

Comment: Nice to meet a time traveller

Comment: What day is it tomorrow?

Comment: I have multiple personality disorder.

Comment: @RobertColumbia me too!

Comment: @RobertColumbia did you receive a ping message for pinging your other self? If not: bug.

Comment: @Gimby: Obviously, this question isn't about my account. Can't you all just stop trying to be funny? I know, this is meta, but noise is still noise.

Comment: @IInspectable I can't honor that request, however I do feel bad for responding to a series of jokes that has run its course long ago. Don't outlaw meta humor because I went out of line.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, this happens when you merge two accounts that both have developer stories with that entry.

The "Joined Stack Overflow" entries can be deleted from your developer story like any other entries, so the user can do that and leave the one they think is appropriate.