# Developer story job - current job range calculation

Tags: discussion, bug, developer-story

It's saying that from April to now it's 11 months long, which is totally false. Any logical explanation I'm missing?

This info is in [my](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/9942418) developer story view.

EDIT: Due to "reasons" I've made my developer story private. To reproduce the bug just go to your own developer story and see your current position's range calculation and you'll find it off by 1 month.

Also this post was made in January 2019, which is the "current" in the picture below.

[image: bug]

Comment: (Apr, May, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec, Jan) = 10 ... and since we are almost at Feb, it's then 11, logical no? better have more than less :)

Comment: @TemaniAfif I don't know, something is still bugging me, cuz you usually don't start counting from April :P And even if you did, it should be 10 and not 11 as you pointed out

Comment: isn't 2019 a leap year for all months..? or probably not..

Comment: "You usually don't start counting from April".. well, when did you start working? How I understand it, April counts as "the first month I worked" so @TemaniAfif's count makes sense to me

Comment: LinkedIn is counting the starting month too, but still, I agree here is a bug. (I checked and for me here it says there are 6 months since September, while LinkedIn says 5->neither actually accurate)

Comment: @GPhilo I started working at 9th of April. So, `9th April -> 9th May` (1 month), `9th May-> 9th June` (2 month), `9th June-> 9th July` (3 month), `9th July-> 9th August` (4 month), `9th August-> 9th September` (5 month), `9th September-> 9th October` (6 month), `9th October-> 9th November` (7 month), `9th November-> 9th December` (8 month), `9th December-> 9th January` (9 month), `9th January-> current` (10 month). Knowing that I still didn't finish my 10th month I've technically been working for 9 months, that's why you start counting from May and not from April :-)

Comment: Not really "totally false", just a little [off by one error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error). Like would anyone care. Do you?

Comment: @GPhilo I started my job on Sep 29, and on Oct 1st I was already having 2 months on LInkedin, so to me, it doesn't make sense to count the first month :)

Comment: @Sinatr it's not about caring, it's about pointing out that a bug exists.

Comment: Right, I somehow counted 11 elements in that list :P

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy, not all bugs are bugs (has to be fixed). How important is to know accurately value in months? I doubt +/-1 makes a difference here. There is a date (April 2018) if you need accuracy.

Comment: Coming to a bug reporting section and asking why people care about a bug - +1

Comment: FWIW mine is similar. Sep 2012 to now says 6y 6m, which is really only 5 months, unless you include the WHOLE of Feb for the extra month...

Comment: Am I the only one to notice that this profile has a [Joined Stack Overflow. Twice!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/365367/2173917) case? :)

Comment: Thats because SE is always [living in the future](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/378872/7322095).

Comment: For the past few years, I've been constantly reminded by people on birthdays, that if they are turning `x`th age, it is actually said that they are running in the `x+1`th year.

Comment: I think it's not up to us (users) to decide whether this sort of bug is indeed a bug and/or should be fixed. OP was correct in pointing out something was weird, but it's up to SO devs/admins to decide whether this should be considered a bug, and what is the priority of fixing this (if they're going to fix it at all). The best we as users can do is report (as OP did).

Comment: This getting upvoted so I hope people won't think I am bad at math looking at the first comment. I simply tried to find a *funny* logic behind this. I am aware that this is a bug but having an extra month is a good think I guess :)